# iOS Webview doesn’t change url when navigating inside SPA

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-router, wkwebview

I’ve created an app with React and Redux where the navigation is done using `Link` from `react-router-dom` and `BrowserRouter`. This makes my page act like expected and like any other SPA, i.e. the state is stored when navigating between pages etc. However, it seems like the Webview inside the Instagram app on iOS doesn’t pick up the changes in the url when using `<Link>`. I tried changing to an anchor tag, `<a>`, and that worked, but that’s not what I want to do. I also tried using an Android phone and that worked as expected with `Link`.

Does anyone know if there is anything I could do, for example pass an extra parameter to the `Link` component? Or is this a bug in the Webview?

Comment: any luck fixing the issue?

Comment: @M.ImranMamda I wasn't able to fix it myself, but it now works as expected for me. I guess the webview is updated with a fix.